# Trying to access return data from a proxy object

Tags: object, post, proxy

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qcJX.png)

Per the picture above, I am to access the data fro, a return proxy object. More specifically the data: "The name field is required. (and 2 more errors)" but having difficulty doing so. I am able to get the validation.error._object and looping through to get the unique key (5ckCQ5WDLJ)that is generated each time but that is all, any pointers?

I tried different variations to access the error data.